# Cannot update to Cordova 3.5.1

Tags: cordova

My company is currently using cordova 3.1. Following this blog post [here](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/08/04/android-351.html), which details serious security vulnerabilities, we need to update to 3.5.1. But when I run:

```
npm view cordova versions
```

The result is:

```
...
...
'3.4.1-0.1.0',
'3.5.0-0.2.0',
'3.5.0-0.2.1',
'3.5.0-0.2.2',
'3.5.0-0.2.3',
'3.5.0-0.2.4',
'3.5.0-0.2.6',
'3.5.0-0.2.7',
'3.6.0-0.2.8',
'3.6.0-0.2.9',
'3.6.1-0.2.10',
'3.6.3-0.2.11',
'3.6.3-0.2.12',
'3.6.3-0.2.13',
'4.0.0',
'4.0.1-nightly.2014.9.29'
```

As you can see, there is no 3.5.1 version. For reasons I wont go in to, we cannot update to 3.6.*. So where is the 3.5.1 version with the security vulnerability patch?

Answer (score 4):

You will look on this site https://www.versioneye.com/nodejs/cordova-js/3.5.1  you will get solution

NPM install --> npm install cordova-js@3.5.1

Direct download ---> http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-js/-/cordova-js-3.5.1.tgz